# Battery Voltages Diagram Help

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I tried to redraw this figure:
[image]

I was able to get this far:

[image]

Can you please help me with that?

My Code

```
                \documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{circuitikz}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=5pt] (0,0) -- (0,3.5);
        \draw[line width=5pt] (8,0) -- (8,3.5);
        \draw[line width=.75pt] (1,4.35) (0,3.5) -- (0,4) -- (3.4,4);
        \draw[line width=.75pt] (1,4.35) (4.6,4) -- (8,4) -- (8,3.5);
        \draw (0,3.5) -- (0,4) to[R={Load}] (8,4) -- (8,3.5);
        \draw[->,line width=.95pt] (1,4.3) -- (2.5, 4.3) node[midway, above] {$i(t)$};
        \draw (3,0) -- (3,3.5);
        \draw (5,0) -- (5,3.5);
        \draw[dashed] (3,1.03) -- (5,1.03);
        \draw[<->] (5.1,1.03) -- (5.1,1.25) node[below right] {$V_{e}$};
        \draw (-0.089,0) -- (8.089,0);
        \draw (-0.089,3.5) -- (8.089,3.5);
        \draw[style=dashed] (0,2.8) -- (8,2.8);
        \draw[style=dashed] (0,2.3) -- (8,2.3);
        \draw[<->] (3.2,2.8) -- (3.2,3.5) node[ midway, right] {$V_{sp}$};
        \draw (0,2.8) .. controls (1.8,3.4) .. (3, 3.5);
        \draw (0,0) .. controls (1.3,.5) .. (3, .6);
        \draw[dashed](0,.45) .. controls (1,.9)  .. (5,1.21);
        \draw[dashed](5,1.21) .. controls (6.5,1.35)  .. (8,1.6);
        \draw(5,1.65) .. controls (6.5,1.75)  .. (8,1.95);
        \draw(5,2.05) .. controls (6.5,2.15)  .. (8,2.3);
        \draw[<->] (2.2,.55) -- (2.2,3.445) node[midway, left] {$V_{Up}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: What's the step you are trying to accomplish now and having trouble with? Is there some reason you can't add further labels as you have the ones you've already got?

Comment: You already got very far, good work!  Which element are you now struggling with?

Comment: Since you have already loaded circuitikz you can simply use `\draw (0,3.5) -- (0,4) to[R={Load}] (8,4) -- (8,3.5);`

Comment: I did updated the code to reflect the above comments. The two small curvy lines above Ve don't match the actual. The two current have arrows line to the left of them (Vs,n, Vn,n and VU,n). Also the text and two curved arrows under the whole graphs.

Comment: If you know the mathematical expression for the curves, you can use that (see page 328 in PGF manual).

Comment: This will draw a current arrow `\draw[thick, -latex] (1,4.25) -- (2.5,4.25) node[midway,above] {$i(t)$};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{circuitikz}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick,scale=1.2]
        % boxes
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (8,3.5);
        \draw[line width=8pt] (0,-0.01) -- (0,3.51) (8,-0.01) -- (8,3.51);
        \draw[fill=gray!20] (3,0) rectangle ++(2,3.5);

        % resistor 
        \draw[thin] (0,3.5) -- ++(0,0.5) to[R={Load},f>^=$i(t)$] ++(8,0) -- ++(0,-0.5);

        % text at the bottom
        \draw (1.5,-0.4)node{Li$_x$CoO$_2$} (4,-0.4)node{Separator} (6.5,-0.4)node{Li$_x$C};                
        \node[anchor=west,inner sep=0pt] (anode) at (0,-1.0) {+ Current Collector};
        \node[anchor=east,inner sep=0pt] (cathode) at (8,-1.0) {- Current Collector};
        \draw[->] (anode.north) to[in=-90,out=150] (0,-0.05);  
        \draw[->] (cathode.north) to[in=-90,out=30] (8,-0.05);

        % dashed lines
        \draw[dashed] (0,2.8) -- (8,2.8)node[right=8pt]{$\phi_s(0,t)$};
        \draw[dashed] (0,2.3) -- (8,2.3)node[right=8pt]{$\phi_s(L,t)$};
        \draw[dashed] (3,1.03) -- (5,1.03);

        % solid curves        
        \draw (0,2.8) .. controls (1.8,3.4) .. (3, 3.5);
        \draw (0,0.0) .. controls (1.3,0.5) .. (3, 0.6);
        \draw (5,1.5) .. controls (6,1.75) and (7,1.5)  .. (8,1.95);
        \draw (5,1.9) .. controls (6,2.15) and (7,1.9)  .. (8,2.33);

        % dashed curve      
        \draw[densely dashed](0,.45) 
        .. controls (1.0,.9) and (2.0,0.9) .. (3,1.03)
        .. controls (4,1.2)  and (4.3,1.2) .. (5,1.21)
        .. controls (6,1.35) and (7.0,1.4) .. (8,1.6);

        % arrows
        \draw[<->] (-0.3,2.3) -- node[left]{$V(t)$} (-0.3,2.8);
        \draw[<->,thin] (5.1,1.03) -- (5.1,1.25) node[below right] {$V_{e}$};
        \draw[<->] (3.2,2.8) -- (3.2,3.5) node[ midway, right] {$V_{s,p}$};
        \draw[<->] (2.2,.55) -- (2.2,3.445) node[midway, left] {$V_{Up}$};
        \draw[<->] (4.7,2.3) -- (4.7,1.9) node[midway,left] {$V_{s,n}$};
        \draw[<->] (4.7,1.9) -- (4.7,1.5) node[midway,left] {$V_{\eta,n}$};
        \draw[<->] (4.7,1.5) -- (4.7,1.2) node[midway,left] {$V_{U,n}$};                

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]